# Scala: list matching with/without substitution

Tags: scala, pattern-matching, substitution

Here are functions definitions that work fine:

```
case class Type(unique:String, tech:String)
case class TVal(tech:String, value:String)

  def f1(techName:String, variables: List[TVal]):String =
    variables.filter(variable =>
      techName == variable.tech)
      .map(variable => variable.value) match {
      case Nil => "empty list"
      case head::Nil => head
      case head::tail => "more than one"
    }

  def f2(defList:List[Type],
         variables: List[TVal]):List[Tuple2[String,String]] =
    defList.map(t => {
      t.unique -> f1(t.tech, variables)
    })

  def comp(defList:List[Type],
           variables: List[TVal]):Map[String,String] =
    Map(f2(defList, variables): _*)
```

Now I try to substitute each function invocation with its body:

```
  def compSubstitution(defList:List[Type],
                       variables: List[TVal]):Map[String,String] =
    Map(defList.map(t => {
      t.unique -> variables.filter(variable =>
        t.tech == variable.tech)
        .map(variable => variable.value) match {
        case Nil => "empty list"
        case head::Nil => head
        case head::tail => "more than one"
      }
    }): _*)
```

Now I am getting a compilation errors:

```
Error:(33, 14) pattern type is incompatible with expected type;
 found   : scala.collection.immutable.Nil.type
 required: (String, List[String])
        case Nil => "empty list"
Error:(33, 14) type mismatch;
 found   : scala.collection.immutable.Nil.type
 required: (String, List[String])
        case Nil => "empty list"
Error:(34, 18) constructor cannot be instantiated to expected type;
 found   : scala.collection.immutable.::[B]
 required: (String, List[String])
        case head::Nil => head
Error:(35, 18) constructor cannot be instantiated to expected type;
 found   : scala.collection.immutable.::[B]
 required: (String, List[String])
        case head::tail => "more than one"
Error:(29, 20) type mismatch;
 found   : List[String]
 required: Seq[(String, String)]
    Map(defList.map(t => {
```

How it could be? Can you please describe?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are matching a type (String -> List[String]) to a Nil and you want to match only the List right?

So i think you are only missing parenthesis:

```
def compSubstitution(defList:List[Type], variables: List[TVal]):Map[String,String] =
   Map(defList.map(t => {
t.unique ->(
  variables.filter(variable => t.tech == variable.tech)
  .map(variable => variable.value) match {
  case Nil => "empty list"
  case head::Nil => head
  case head::tail => "more than one"
})
   }): _*)
```

Comment: thank you, it works! Not clear, why it is required.